# scanf from data buffer in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, file, scanf

I'm working with a closed piece of hardware and I want to load a text file. I only have the following function to access secondary memory:

```
bool load_file(const char *filename, int **buf, int *size)
```

This means I would end up with all the data in buf and the size of it in size. How could I extract strings, integers or float data from it? I would like to do it in a similar why as using scanf.

Thanks.

Comment: it depends on how the data is laid out in `buf`.

Comment: Depends very much on how it was filled. An `int ** buf` doesn't directly indicate a text stream.

Comment: there's sscanf, but you have to convert the byte array into a char array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sscanf` to scan memory blocks instead of files, similar to the way you can use `sprintf` to `printf` into memory. The prototype is:

```
int sscanf (const char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

In other words, the same as `scanf` but with a pointer added.

That's for turning character data into other types. If you have *raw* data in that memory buffer, you can cast and de-reference.

In other words, say you have a memory buffer with an integer starting at the fifth location (offset 4), something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    //                +--------------+--> little-endian,
    //                |              |       32-bit = 42.
    char xyz[] = "1234\x2a\x00\x00\x00";
    int x = *((int*)(xyz+4));
    printf ("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming your integer encoding are the same as mine, this outputs 42 (hex 2A). Taking that expression apart one bit at a time:

```
        (xyz+4)  : Get the address four unit past xyz. Since xyz is a char
                   pointer, this means four bytes.
  (int*)(xyz+4)  : Cast it into an int pointer.
*((int*)(xyz+4)) : De-reference that to get the int at that address.
```